# Is it possible to win a level after the countdown from firing your gun is over?

Tags: gunpoint

If you fire your gun in any level there is a countdown. When the countdown ends police blocks the exit and shoots you on sight and it seems like it's impossible to kill them.
It seems to be impossible to finish the level since you cant't reach the exit.
Is there really no way to win the level in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you have only one option:
**Shoot the police officer standing at the subway entrance**.

To do this you have to be standing somewhere where he cannot see you - so you don't get shot first - so firing from somewhere inside and dark, such as a darkened window or doorway will work.

It wouldn't surprise me if this wasn't possible on all levels.

Comment: As you said it probably isn't possible in some levels. I tried that quite a bit in one level but it was like the bullets wasn't reaching him and if I got any closer than that he would shoot me instead. So I just assumed it was impossible to shoot him. I will test this in other levels.

Comment: I tested and confirmed this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky with level selection, some buildings will be too close and you can use gatecrashers on the sniper

Answer (score 0):

On the last level I found it's possible to gank the sniper at the subway if you get there first and have your gun ready before the countdown ends.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, on most levels. You can turn off the lights and the sniper won't see you, therefore you can get your gun and shoot him, it wont spawn another sniper until you shoot again.